# Salvar o carrinho de compras quando uma transação é negada e página redirecionada

Tags: woocommerce

O meu gateway de pagamento tem um problema quando um transação é negada, ele redireciona para uma outra página de pagamento que está toda bugada, então criei uma segunda página de checkout e estou tentando redirecionar o pagamento negado para essa página (redireciono para uma duplicata do meu checkout porque fiz algumas modificações nela, informando que o pagamento foi negado, etc), criei a seguinte função:

```
function redirect_after_failed( $order_id, $order ) {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'order-pay' ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart( false );
        wp_redirect( '/finalizar-2' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'redirect_after_failed');
```

Funciona corretamente quando o usuário está logado em uma conta, porém em minha loja os compradores não criam contas, ou seja, funciona só para mim na conta de administrador.

O problema que encontrei é que o carrinho só é salvo e não apagado quando está com uma conta conectada, quando são visitantes o carrinho não é salvo e é apagado.

Estou a dias tentando encontrar uma solução para salvar os carrinhos de visitantes e quando serem redirecionados os carrinhos see manterem, para poderem ir ao segundo checkout.

Desde já agradeço.